# Correct usage of Interpolations.jl outside the domain

Tags: julia

I'm porting a Matlab code into julia and so far i'm having amazing results:
A code that in Matlab runs in more than 5 hours, julia does it in a little more than 8 minutes! however i have a problem...
In matlab i have:

```
    for xx=1:xlong
        for yy = 1:ylong
            U_alturas(xx,yy,:) = interp1(squeeze(NivelAltura_int(xx,yy,:)),squeeze(U(xx,yy,:)), interpolar_a);
            V_alturas(xx,yy,:) = interp1(squeeze(NivelAltura_int(xx,yy,:)),squeeze(V(xx,yy,:)), interpolar_a);
        end
    end
```

that produces NaNs whenever a point in interpolar_a is outside the range in NivelAltura_int.

In Julia i'm trying to do the same with:

```
for xx in 1:xlong
    for yy in 1:ylong
        AltInterp = interpolate((Znw_r,),A_s_c_r,Gridded(Linear()));
        NivelAltura_int[xx,yy,1:end] = AltInterp[Znu[1:end]]
        Uinterp = interpolate((squeeze(NivelAltura_int[xx,yy,1:end],(1,2)),),squeeze(U[xx,yy,1:end],(1,2)),Gridded(Linear()));
        Vinterp = interpolate((squeeze(NivelAltura_int[xx,yy,1:end],(1,2)),),squeeze(V[xx,yy,1:end],(1,2)),Gridded(Linear()));
        U_alturas[xx,yy,1:end] = Uinterp[Alturas[1:end]];
        V_alturas[xx,yy,1:end] = Vinterp[Alturas[1:end]];
    end
end
```

using the package Interpolations.jl. Whenever the point is outside the domain, this package extrapolates, which is incorrect for my purposes. 
I can add a few lines of code that check and substitutes the values outside the domain with NaNs, but i believe it would add some time to the computation and is not very elegant.

In the documentation of the package, it mentions a kind of object like this:

```
        Uextrap = extrapolate(Uinterp,NaN)
```

To control the behavior outside the domain, but i haven't find how to use it, i've tried adding it under Uinterp, i've tried evaluating it but it, naturally, won't work that way.

Could you help me on this one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you may be running into two issues here.  First, there's been some recent work on gridded extrapolations ([#101](https://github.com/tlycken/Interpolations.jl/pull/101)) that may not be in the tagged version yet.  If you're willing to live on the edge, you can `Pkg.checkout("Interpolations")` to use the development version (`Pkg.free("Interpolations")` will put you back on the stable version again).

Secondly, it looks like there's a still a missing method for vector-valued gridded extrapolations ([issue #24](https://github.com/tlycken/Interpolations.jl/issues/24)):

```
julia> using Interpolations
       itp = interpolate((collect(1:10),), collect(.1:.1:1.), Gridded(Linear()))
       etp = extrapolate(itp, NaN);

julia> etp[.5:1:10.5]
ERROR: BoundsError: # ...
 in throw_boundserror at abstractarray.jl:156
 in getindex at abstractarray.jl:488
```

As you can see, it's trying to use the generic definitions for all abstract arrays, which will of course throw bounds errors.  Interpolations just needs to add its own definition.

In the mean time, you can use a comprehension with scalar indexing:

```
julia> [etp[x] for x=.5:1:10.5]
11-element Array{Any,1}:
 NaN
   0.15
   0.25
   0.35
   0.45
   0.55
   0.65
   0.75
   0.85
   0.95
 NaN
```

Answer (score 3):

The following sample ([refer](https://github.com/tlycken/Interpolations.jl/blob/master/test/extrapolation/runtests.jl)) shows how `extrapolate` works:

Preparation:

```
using Interpolations
f(x) = sin((x-3)*2pi/9 - 1)
xmax = 10
A = Float64[f(x) for x in 1:xmax] # domain .EQ. 1:10
itpg = interpolate(A, BSpline(Linear()), OnGrid())
```

The `itpg` object extrapolates outside points conforming its interpolation type:

```
itpg[2] # inside => -0.99190379965505 
itpg[-2] # outside => 0.2628561875219271
```

Now we use `extrapolat` object to control extrapolation behavior:

```
etpg = extrapolate(itpg, NaN);
etpg[2]==itpg[2] # same result when point is inside => true
isnan(etpg[-2])   # NaN when the point is outside => true
```

So an `extrapolate` object does interpolation conforming its parent while extrapolates in a custom manner.